# Using msdeploy parameters.xml with VSTS releases without tokens

Tags: azure-devops, msdeploy

I'm trying to work out if it's possible to use `parameters.xml` with VSTS releases without the need to replace tokens in the default values.

The method of using tokens as default values works (as explained https://blog.ehn.nu/2016/03/using-web-deploy-in-visual-studio-team-services-release-management/) just fine but I think it's unnecessary and I want to find out if I'm missing something.

As an example I have this parameter in parameters.xml

```
<parameter name="ExamineExternalIndexSet" description="" defaultvalue="" tags="">
  <parameterentry kind="XmlFile" scope="\\ExamineIndex\.config$"
                match="/ExamineLuceneIndexSets/IndexSet[@SetName='ExternalIndexSet']/@IndexPath">
  </parameterentry>
</parameter>
```

I think that a VSTS release should match the parameter name `ExamineExternalIndexSet` with a environment variable of the same name when deploying to a environment (this is the case in other tools such as `AppVeyor`) however it doesn't appear to work.

Anything I'm missing or does VSTS simply not do this matching and I need to use the token replacement on the defaultValue?

Comment: Which task do you use to deploy?

Comment: "Deploy Azure App Service" with "Publish using Web Deploy" checked and SetParameters file path set.